# Pass $(location) to Bazel --test_arg

Tags: c++, junit, bazel, catch2

**The question**

Is it possible to pass a general `$(location)` to `bazel test` in the `--test_args` argument which is re-evaluated for each executed test?

**Context**

What I am trying to do is use `bazel test` to bulk execute tests, but produce unique output files.

I am using Catch2 with the `--out` argument to specify a JUnit XML output file location.  I could have Catch2 output the JUnit to `STDOUT`, but the test.log gets somewhat polluted with test data produced by Bazel, and any other `STDOUT`, or `STDERR` that Catch2 produces.

*eg. I am trying to produce the following:*

> - ./bazel-testlogs/
>
>   - Folder
>
>     - Tests
>
>       - Test1
>
>         - Test1_JUNIT.xml
>       - Test2
>
>         - Test2_JUNIT.xml

Answer (score 0):

We ended up patching Catch2 to look for the `XML_OUTPUT_FILE` environment variable, and use that as the report output path.  The inspiration came from [this similar post](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1748485).